# Assign hash key and value from string using split

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a few strings that I am retrieving from a file `birthdays.txt`. An example of a string is below:

```
Christopher Alexander, Oct 4, 1936
```

I would like to separate the strings and let variable `name` be a hash key and `birthdate` the hash value. Here is my code:

```
birthdays = {}
File.read('birthdays.txt').each_line do |line|
  line = line.chomp 
  name, birthdate = line.split(/\s*,\s*/).first
  birthdays = {"#{name}" => "#{birthdate}"}
  puts birthdays
end
```

I managed to assign `name` to the key. However, `birthdate` returns `""`.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.new('birthdays.txt').each.with_object({}) do
  |line, birthdays|
  birthdays.store(*line.chomp.split(/\s*,\s*/, 2))
  puts birthdays
end
```

Comment: That third line (`Hash#store` with a splat) is clever. 

Answer (score 1):

I feel like some of the other solutions are overthinking this a bit. All you need to do is split each line into two parts, the part before the first comma and the part after, which you can do with `line.split(/,\s*/, 2)`, then call `to_h` on the resulting array of arrays:

```
data = <<END
Christopher Alexander, Oct 4, 1936
Winston Churchill, Nov 30, 1874
Max Headroom, Apr 4, 1985
END

data.each_line.map do |line|
  line.chomp.split(/,\s*/, 2)
end.to_h
# => { "Christopher Alexander" => "Oct 4, 1936",
#      "Winston Churchill" => "Nov 30, 1874",
#      "Max Headroom" => "April 4, 1985" }
```

(You will, of course, want to replace `data` with your File object.)

Answer (score 0):

```
birthdays = Hash.new

File.read('birthdays.txt').each_line do |line|
  line = line.chomp 

  name, birthdate = line.split(/\s*,\s*/, 2)
  birthdays[name]= birthdate

  puts birthdays
end
```

Comment: This will result in values that are the part of each line following the last comma, e.g. `"1936"` instead of `"Oct 4, 1936"`, which I don't think is what OP wants. You don't need to call `String#split` twice—take a look at @sawa's answer or my own if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Jordan's `data`:

```
data.each_line.with_object({}) do |line, h|
  name, _, bdate = line.chomp.partition(/,\s*/)
  h[name] = bdate
end
  #=> {"Christopher Alexander"=>"Oct 4, 1936",
  #    "Winston Churchill"=>"Nov 30, 1874",
  #    "Max Headroom"=>"Apr 4, 1985"}
```